# Access Student Data via Gaurdian

Tags: google-classroom

I'm the president of SchoolBlocks.com and am doing research on the Classroom API through the eyes of a parent.  I'm trying to understand how to access calendar data of a student in which a guardian has been connected.  What permissions does the guardian need to give in order to view their child's classroom calendar(s)?

Comment: Do you mean to see the calendar through the API? Or how to create a guardian with the API that is able to see classroom activity?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, I think it would be the student who needs to give permission to the guardian.

There are a few possible approaches, depending on the scale of the solution etc.

1. The student could simply [share their calendar](https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/37082?hl=en) with their guardian.
2. Programatically it would be possible via the [Calendar API](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/list), the auth would either be via OAuth or a service account and require the following scopes: ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.events"]
3. Reach out to a Google Build partner.